# WP phone call task does not allow another operation to be running while call is in progress

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, text-to-speech, telephony

I have a bit of a problem here, I am developing an app which speaks to the recipient of a call via WP's Speech Recognition. The problem comes about while trying to get this to actually work. Obviously, both APIs exist, but they seem to cancel each other out.

Code:

```
    PhoneCallTask pht = new PhoneCallTask();
    pht.PhoneNumber = "NUMBER";
    pht.DisplayName = "APP NAME";
    pht.Show();
    SpeechSynthesizer spc = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    spc.SpeakTextAsync("TEXT TO SPEAK HERE");
```

It seems to speak the first few letters of the text, if any at all, then stop while the phone call task executes. How can I get these two operations to execute at the same time?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't.

Comment: Are there any web services which would make a telephone call or something then? Or any other options?